# when action clicked it fails to display in control

Tags: text, label

Issue = unable to reflect button action (sets label text) to Label

---

- Explanation back ground -

i have two basic buttons defined (as Actions) &  I have one label (serves as control)
- see below

---

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UILabel *stopWatchLabel;

}
- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

---

I have implimented it below such that when i click the Start or Stop button it should reflect in the label --- see below -

```
- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
    stopWatchLabel.text = @"START PRESSED";
}

- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {
 stopWatchLabel.text = @"STOP PRESSED";
}
```

---

However when i click on the START button or the STOP button (when i run the program), nothing happens ?

someone kindly tell me what am i missing

---